# Duplicates with INNER JOIN even with DISTINCT

Tags: php, mysql, distinct

Since I added images from another table, it gives me duplicates and I have no clue why. I already put in DISTINCT but without any result.

Here you can see the table "fotos". The results of my code would be two times "Internnummer 1" and three times "Internnummer 2".

> Internnummer | VolgNR | Fotonaam 
>   1 | 0 | Image_1.jpg 
>   1 | 1 | Image_2.jpg 
>   2 | 0 | Image_3.jpg 
>   2 | 1 | Image_4.jpg 
>   2 | 2 | Image_5.jpg

In the code I already made it work that only images with "VolgNr" 0 will be displayed. But still, it duplicates the rest of the data.

Everything works fine whenever I use this, except for the image of course.

> sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM occasions INNER JOIN fotos ON occasions.Internnummer = fotos.Internnummer";

Full Code:

```
<?php

    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM occasions INNER JOIN fotos ON occasions.Internnummer = fotos.Internnummer";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo
            "<div class='oc-item'>" .
            // Product image
            "<div class='oc-image'>" .
            "<img src='http://example.com/images/" . ($row['VolgNr'] == 0 ? $row["Fotonaam"] : $row['OmschrijvingNL']) . "'/>" .
            "</div>".
            // Product information
            "<div class='oc-info'><b>" .
            "<a href=\"occasion?id=".$row['Internnummer']."\" >". $row["OmschrijvingNL"]. "</a>" .
            "</b>".
            "<p>" . ($row['Prijs'] == 0 ? 'Prijs op aanvraag' : $row['Prijs']) . "</p><br />" .
            "<p>" .
            $row["Memotekst1NL"]. "</p>" . "<p>" .
            $row["Memotekst2NL"]. "</p>" . "<p>" .
            $row["Memotekst3NL"]. "</p>" . "<p>" .
            $row["Memotekst4NL"]. "</p>" . "<p>" .
            $row["Memotekst5NL"]. "</p>" . "<p>" .
            "<a href=\"occasion?id=".$row['Internnummer']."\" >"."Lees meer..."."</a>" .
            "</div>" .

            "</div>";

            }

    } else {
        echo "Geen resultaten gevonden.";
    }
?>
```

Comment: DISTINCT means that every row is unique, not that it won't repeat data from your base table. Use grouping that suits your needs or use something for hydration.

Comment: Yeah, I get that but not every row is unique, right...? The duplicates have all the same "Internummer". The only difference they have is the image but whenever I delete the full image it still shows duplicates while it should only check the "Internnummer".

Comment: In example you gave us, rows are unique, there are no duplicates. Looks like you don't get joins? And `DISTINCT *` is equal to `group by` using all fields from all tables in their order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was kinda easy to resolve. I added WHERE and the duplicates are gone.

```
SELECT * FROM fotos INNER JOIN occasions ON occasions.Internnummer = fotos.Internnummer WHERE VolgNr = 0
```